# Variable name same as the type of the object?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I've been told multiple times to never ever do things like:

```
Dog   dog   = new Dog();
Entry entry = new Entry();
//etc...
```

Notice how the `Type`/`Object` name is `Dog` and the `variable` name is `dog`. Is it truly considered bad programming to do something like this, or is it just frowned upon? How does this induce bad readability to another person reading YOUR program?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I don't see anything bad with it, this is opinion based question

Comment: No it isn't opinion based...

Comment: Usually you can have a better name for a variable to denote the particular intent of having it here. Like `dogToDraw` or `userEntry` or `receivedAccount`. I wouldn't say that you should "never ever" do things like that though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Feel free to post some *objective* and *indisputable* facts about this ;0

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Care to elaborate?

Comment: This not a bad practice as long as you keep casing according to the convention: start with upper case for class name and lower case for variable name.

Comment: I have done so, hopefully in a way that doesn't further confuse the issue. :)

Comment: Sure, private int something; public int Something {get {return Something;} or how about wolf = new Dog(). There are loads of reasons not to do it, very very few where using something other than differing case would reduce comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bad idea per se but it really depends about the meaning of your objects. I'll make it clear with an example:

```
class Engine {

}

class Car {
  private Engine engine;
}
```

You can see here that naming the instance variable `engine` doesn't do anything bad about readability. a `Car` has an `engine` and in this case the name of the class and of the instance variable don't create any problem.

But consider another example:

```
class Point {

}

class Circle {
  private Point point;
}
```

Here you can see why it is not a good idea in all circumstances. A `Circle` has a `Point` called `point`. Good but what is this point? Calling it just `point` is not informative to the reader. Maybe `center` would have been more appropriate.

Usually a class name represents a cluster of all possible objects of that type. This means that its name is usually generic. This means that in general having an instance variable with the same name of the object should be not enough informative, of course there are situations in which everything you need to understand can be deduced from the context (see the `Car` example) but you should really consider the specific case.

Comment: Thanks, this totally clears things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with giving a variable, a name in the likeness of its type.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Entry entry = new Entry()
```

are both perfectly reasonable. Both examples also meet Java naming recommendations e.g. camel case variable names, classes begin with a capitable letter, etc...